# Where can I find a list (even if only partial) of excipients that cause a medication to be indivisible?

Tags: medications

Certain tablet formulations should not be divided or halved because the tablets are film-coated for low pH resistance (i.e. for safe passage in the stomach) or because the active ingredient is not uniformly dispersed within the tablet. Now, usually the package leaflet indicates if the tablet can indeed be halved/crushed or not, but many times it does not, so I wanted to be able to deduce this piece of information from the excipients list, but I was unable to find some kind of a list that summarizes the most common excipients that mean that the coating or the formulation render the tablet indivisible. I know they are usually polymers, such as ethylcellulose, but I want more information. Any suggestions?

(I posted this on Chemistry SE too, because the question deals with the chemistry of the coating, but it was closed as off-topic. I disagree with that label, but perhaps here will be more "on-topic"?)